# zeppelin (0.9.0) helium s3 folder unavailable

Tags: apache-zeppelin

when enabling the helium folder in the zeppelin-site.xml the default s3 bucket returns 403
for

ERROR [2023-08-01 14:23:24,964] ({qtp1383547042-15} HeliumOnlineRegistry.java[getAll]:103) - https://s3.amazonaws.com/helium-package/helium.json returned HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

**Update**
A workaround that appears to be working, in my case logging into to the container as root

- apt udpate
- apt install npm
- cd /opt/zeppelin/local-repo/vis
- npm install zeppelin-highcharts-heatmap
- copy the node-modules/zeppelin-highcharts-heatmap/zeppelin-highcharts-heatmap.conf /opt/zeppelin/conf